# How to update state in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to ask if there is any better way to update state in react.js.

I wrote this code below but just updating state takes many steps and I wonder if I'm doing in a right way.

Any suggestion?

How about immutable.js? I know the name of it but I've never used it and don't know much about it.

## code

```
toggleTodoStatus(todoId) {

    const todosListForUpdate = [...this.state.todos];
    const indexForUpdate = this.state.todos.findIndex((todo) => {
        return todo.id === todoId;
    });

    const todoForUpdate = todosListForUpdate[indexForUpdate];
    todoForUpdate.isDone = !todoForUpdate.isDone;

    this.setState({
        todos: [...todosListForUpdate.slice(0, indexForUpdate), todoForUpdate, ...todosListForUpdate.slice(indexForUpdate + 1)]
    })

}
```

Comment: `const newTodos = this.state.todos.map(t => t.id === todoId ? { ...t, isDone: !t.isDone } : t);` (as of today - it requires `stage-3` due to object spread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an extra step that you don't need. Directly setting value to the cloned object and restting back to state will work

```
toggleTodoStatus(todoId) {

    const todosListForUpdate = [...this.state.todos];
    const indexForUpdate = this.state.todos.findIndex((todo) => {
        return todo.id === todoId;
    });

    todosListForUpdate[indexForUpdate].isDone = !todosListForUpdate[indexForUpdate].isDone;

    this.setState({
        todos: todosListForUpdate
    })

}
```

Comment: Unless `todosListForUpdate[indexForUpdate]` is not cloned.